# Check for login activities of last 10 minutes (Actual time) in auth.log file?

Tags: bash, date, unix, auth.log

I have a cronjob that executes a bash file every 10 min. The bash file contains a Curl command that sends me a sms if var/log/auth.log file contains any lines with "Accepted password for". (obviously the if condition is true every time).
Now i want to add another if condition that checks for string "Accepted password for" ONLY FOR LAST 10 MIN of time.

My problem is, the log file contains the time info like this:

```
Sep  5 13:49:07 localhost sshd[565]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.

Nov 28 21:39:25 soft-server sshd[11946]: Accepted password for myusername from 10.0.2.2 port 13494 ssh2
```

How can I compare current time with above format and write an IF statement?
Currently i'm doing this:

```
if [ grep -q "Accepted password for" var/log/auth.log] && (check timing for last 10 min)
then
    curl 'www.example.com/send-a-text'
fi
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not `tac` the file, pipe it to `grep` so you have the output in reverse order (newest first) and then use *process substitution* to feed a loop, e.g. `while read -r m d t rest; do if (( ($(date +%s) - $(date -d "$m $d $t" + %s)) <= 600 )); then # login less than 10 min. old - handle line; else break; fi; done < <(tac var/log/auth.log | grep "Accepted password for")` If the log is small, then forget reversing it with `tac` and just feed the loop with the output from `grep` (adjusting the test and `break` as required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to compare times is to convert them to seconds from epoch, that way you can just treat them as integers. Here's an example:

```
#! /bin/bash

# time in seconds from epoch 10 minutes ago is the limit
limit="$(date -d '10 minutes ago' +%s)"
# read matches from the file starting from the end up to the limit
while read -r logrow; do
    # cut out the timestamp from the logrow
    timestamp="$(cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3 <<<"$logrow")"
    # convert timestamp to seconds from epoch
    from_epoch="$(date -d "$timestamp" +%s)"
    # if the line was newer than 10 minutes ago, send a message
    if (( from_epoch > limit )); then
        # send the logrow
        curl "www.example.com/send-a-text?logrow=${logrow}"
    else
        # after reaching the limit, stop the loop
        break
    fi
done < <(tac /var/log/auth.log | grep "Accepted")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! but now the problem is, it sends me only 1 sms, no matter how many logins are  done in last 10 min.  Maybe i was not clear in my queston but i want  to get all the login info and possibly append that info to my curl URL.  
For ex: curl 'www.example.com/send-a-text/user=name&number=12345678&text=$IP_ADDRESS

Comment: See my edit, you should be able to figure out how to grep just the ip address etc. from the `$logrow` if you don't want to send the whole row.

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much.